# Are questions about how to Navigate/Use Online MTG retailers considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

I came across this question while browsing the [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) tag:

[Can I look up a large list of cards on MagicCardMarket.eu?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/36831/15514)

> MagicCardMarket.eu is apparently the go-to store for buying Magic cards in Europe, and I'm using it for the first time. I've a list of cards I'd like to buy to finalise a deck, and I can't find any way to search for them except one by one. Is there some way I can input a "want list" or something like that into MagicCardMarket.eu so that I can pick out the cards I need from sellers a bunch at a time?

I have not seen any similar questions before, and the [online-stores](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-stores) tag it uses, only has the linked question.

Are these types of questions considered on-topic for Board & Card Games, or should the questions be more about the actual games themselves?

Comment: related: https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1194/409

Comment: There's a precedent of sorts: One a couple of occasions, we've helped people looking to identify a MTG card they had previously seen by teaching them how to use the available search engines rather than just giving the answer.

Comment: Re "*the [tag:online-stores] tag it uses, only has the linked question*", This means it will cease to exist unless someone create a wiki for it.

Answer (score 4):

I think they're on topic. Different Stack sites have different ways to examine topicality, but I'll examine it using some rules of thumb that are usually pretty relevant:

- **Is it substantially related to our topic?** Yes. Buying, selling and trading is an integral part of playing Magic: the Gathering. Online marketplaces are a major way to do that nowadays, so asking how to perform fundamental operations on the major marketplaces is relevant to our topic.
- **Are we the people to ask about this stuff? Is this within our users' topical domain of expertise or experience?** Our community of MTG players almost certainly has collective experience in a number of marketplaces through the course of their gameplay. Our community can be considered experts on these.
- **Are people going to expect to look here for this stuff?** If we're helping people handle the game itself, yes.

I'll note that we accept many types of questions that take place at a meta level above/outside the game itself:

- We accept flavor questions: [Are questions about flavor acceptable?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/are-questions-about-flavor-acceptable)
- And tournament behaviours: [Are questions about tournament play/behaviour on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/are-questions-about-tournament-play-behaviour-on-topic) (but not super-generic questions that could be related to any tournament or any event ever)
- And pricing and value questions: [Are pricing and value questions on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/are-pricing-and-value-questions-on-topic)
- And we accept guidance on how to handle the basics of selling: [Where can I sell my Magic: The Gathering cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/where-can-i-sell-my-magic-the-gathering-cards)

I'm primarily active on RPG Stack Exchange, where people use various toolsets (such as the online virtual tabletop web app Roll20) to run their games and we facilitate questions on usage of those toolsets. I think this is the same kind of thing.

Comment: I agree not only about this but about the general idea of game-adjacent questions. (Feels awkward calling them "meta" given that this is meta?) I know we can't handle *everything* (recommendations too broad, etc) but insofar as the questions fit the format, I think we should handle as much about board/card games as we can, and only consider making things off-topic if we discover that they cause issues.

Answer (score -2):

I would think they would be off topic as it would be the case of any site used for buying and selling of games and gaming components. It is hard to see how the use of a commerce website falls into the realm of this site.